# Substring with the loop

Tags: java, string, exception, substring

In below code I am trying to do substring based on start and end index,But in end of the string.System is throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Please let me know, how to resolve this issue.

```
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int initlength = 20;
        int start = 0;
        String s = "Some people confuse acceptance with apathy, but there's all "+
"the difference in the world";
        int total=(int)Math.ceil((double)s.length()/(double)initlength);
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            System.out.println("s length" + s.substring(start, initlength));
            start = initlength + 1;
            initlength = initlength + initlength;
            }
    }
```

Regards,

chaitu

Comment: @ user569125 : I have executed this code and exception is generated.

Comment: so, uh...what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? 0_0

Comment: sthupahsmaht:Here i am looping the entire string and getting the part of the string based on start and end.in above code total lenght of my string is :87,start=0,length to retrieve is 20.finally start became 81 and end lenght became 100.But i want to retrive 81 to 87 th string?

Comment: @user569125: so, you want to read a string in 20 character chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step by step debug your code:

1. first time variables

   `start=0;
   initlength=0;
   s="Some people confuse acceptance with apathy, but there's all the difference in the world"; 
   total = 5.`
2. `s.length()/initlength = 4.`
3. first substring will be from 0 to 20.
4. `start = 21` and `initlenght = 40`
5. Second time in loop
6. `s.length()/initlength = 2`
7. substring from 21 to 40.
8. `start = 41` and `initlength = 80`.
9. Third time in loop.
10. `s.length()/initlength = 1` and `i` equal to 2 therefore loop will break and program execution will finish.

---

Based on your edit. Now it will loop for 5 times. And after 3rd time `start = 81` and `initlength = 160` which is out of range of string. For all the time `total = 5`.

---

If you want that it will get the remaining part the try this:

```
    int initlength = 20;
    int start = 0;
    String s = "Some people confuse acceptance with apathy, but there's all "
            + "the difference in the world";
    int total = (int) Math.ceil((double) s.length() / (double) initlength);
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        if(initlength<s.length()){
            System.out.println("s length" + s.substring(start, initlength));
            start = initlength + 1;
            initlength = initlength + initlength;
        } else {
            initlength = s.length();
            System.out.println("s length" + s.substring(start, initlength));
            break;
        }
    }
```

output:-

```
s lengthSome people confuse 
s lengthcceptance with apat
s lengthy, but there's all the difference in th
s length world
```

Comment: @Harry Joy:It's not working.if i place System.out.println("s length" + s.substring(start, initlength)); out of if and else conditions

Comment: @user569125: yes of course because then the same thing will happen that is indexOutOfBuonds because you will try to substring using initlength without changing it. The line `initlength = s.length();` in else before `System.out.println("s length" + s.substring(start, initlength));` is necessary to prevent outOfBoundsException. Same for `break;`.

Comment: @ Harry Joy:if i place in end,even it is not substring with starting position 0.

Comment: @user569125: yes because you are changing `start` value in `if` condition so if you place at the end it will produce result for new `start` value. Also don't do that because you will not get desired result as it will also not execute for the last part because of `break;` in `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `initlength` just going to get bigger and bigger until it reaches past the end of the string?